# Grub2 problem after reinstall Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have a dual boot laptop with Windows 8.1 + Ubuntu 16.04. My Windows 8.1 crashed, so I had to reinstall it. After reinstall, Windows boot manager took over and grub2 not coming up any longer. Used Boot Repair utility according to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows), still Grub2 won't come up. Then I followed instructions from `scruss` on the same post, it did bring back the Grub2, but with several entries that I have no idea what they do (I'm afraid to try out in case it messes up Ubuntu). 
The grub menu showed these entries:

```
Ubuntu
Advanced Options for Ubuntu
Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi
Windows Boot UEFI loader
Windows Boot UEFI fbx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
EFI/Ubuntu/mmx64.efi
Windows Boot Manager (on dev/sda4)
System Setup
```

In my grub file I have the following entries:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

How can I clean up the grub file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: this answer specifically https://askubuntu.com/a/326661/307184 boot on an ubuntu live USB and run boot-repair then reboot

Comment: This problem is solved, by re-installing Ubuntu in UEFI mode, the grub is back, so did Windows. Thanks GabrielaGarcia for notifying me of the problem.