# When try to reinstall Ubuntu from USB, grub went to HD instead of USB one

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, uefi

I have a dual boot Win 8 & Ubuntu 16.04, I messed up my grub (please see my [previous post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128324/grub2-problem-after-reinstall-windows-8-1)), not being able to solve it, decided to reinstall Ubuntu, prepared USB stick using 16.04 image and Universal USB installer 1.9.8.8, but whenever tried to boot from USB, the HD grub started instead of USB one, how can I make sure that Ubuntu starts from USB and not HD?

Comment: The early boot order is controlled by the computer's UEFI/BIOS system (before grub and Ubuntu or Windows are started). Please specify your computer: brand name and model. When we know the computer, we can suggest how to make the computer boot from the USB stick.

Comment: @Michael the key to access BIOS before boot is going to be either delete, f2, f12, f11, or f9 depending on the motherboard by order of how common it is. also the bios usually flashes this messages on the screen before boot telling you which key to press to access bios configuration and wich key to press for boot menu. (either one will work for you but I personally always use the BIOS configuration).

Comment: Thank you all for replying to my question, additional tests showed that the problem was on my USB, for some reason, it's not bootable, so I used Startup Disk Creator in Ubuntu and created another one, and this time it worked, so I could re-install Ubuntu, but now I have another problem. As I mentioned before, I had problem using Grub Repair Tool, not sure if this has anything to do with it, but now my Windows 8 is not longer in the grub. When I turn on my pc, it goes straight to Linux, in Ubuntu I can see my C (Windows 8) and D (Data). How do I get Windows back in grub?

Comment: @Michael You may have booted and installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and your Windows is in UEFI. Grub cannot dual-boot in such conditions, all OSes must be installed in the same mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes, you're right, in order to boot from USB, I had to configure my BIOS as legacy, so how can I fix this? I'm trying to avoid using Grub Repair tool, the last time it messed up my install.

Comment: I see my mistake now, how can I solve this? Do I need to reinstall Windows 8 or just reinstall Ubuntu with UEFI USB and the Windows will be back? Is there a safe way to prepare an UEFI USB installer in Ubuntu since I don't have access to Windows any longer, so can't use Rufus.

Comment: This problem is solved, my mistake was installing Ubuntu in legacy mode, after re-installing it in UEFI, the grub is back, so did Windows. Thanks GabrielaGarcia for notifying me of the problem.